# how to maintain scroll position after items have been added to a list in angular

Tags: angular

I have a list of div elements that I am building using an array. I am getting this array from API. the problem is that when the user hits "Load More" button and the new Items are added to the list, the position of the page automatically goes to the end of the list. I want the scroll position to remain at the previous position(at the end of the previous list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just store in a variable the actual position, after subscribe scrool to the position. You need wait to Angular show the data, so, enclosed by setTimeout the scrollTo. Some like

```
this.posY = window.scrollY;
dataService.getMoreData().subscribe((res:any[])=>{
    this.dataList=[...this.dataList,...res];
    setTimeout(()=>{
       window.scrollTo(0,this.posY)
    })
})
```